# window.open different size in IE&FF

Tags: javascript, size, window.open

Code:

```
win3 = window.open("Pages/Login.php", "newwindow", "width=316, height=468");
win3.moveTo(screen.width / 2 - 300, screen.height / 2 - 250);
```

Result:

[image]

Why have different size ?

Comment: Be careful, you just posted your URL in the image at that link. Make sure you want the internet to know about that URL.

Comment: maybe the body or html tag have a default margin or something (CSS) on your Login.php
can you show your css for that page?

Comment: JSK NS: Ty, i remove the URL.
progsource: I'm using in css reset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm fix it with resizeTo() function.

```
win3 = window.open("Pages/Login.php", "newwindow", "width=316, height=468");
win3.resizeTo(316, 468);
win3.moveTo(screen.width / 2 - 300, screen.height / 2 - 250);
```

Ty for help!

Answer (score 0):

From MDN for `strWindowFeatures`: `The string must not contain any whitespace, and each feature name and its value must be separated by a comma`

So,

```
win3 = window.open("Pages/Login.php", "newwindow", "width=316,height=468");
win3.moveTo(screen.width / 2 - 300, screen.height / 2 - 250);
```

should be okay?

Comment: It's not do anything, same result.